# Baffling Review Criteria

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits, link-only-answers

I apparently need some serious help on reviewing.

I failed this audit:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1592156
```

Despite the brevity of this answer it directly addresses the question posed with a knowledgeable resource.  Why was this marked as a flaggable answer?

Comment: guess would be because it's a link only answer & better off as a comment.

Comment: If it _answers_ the question, why should it be a comment? Perhaps (in the interest of educating the reviewers) the _reason_ for the rejection should be stated?

Comment: @vonbrand it's not really a proper answer - merely a pointer. Do read Josh's answer which explains well.

Comment: It should have the link along with some of the code posted there. But I agree with you. I would have chosen "No Action Needed"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This answer was included as an audit because it has been deleted by a moderator. The selection process for audit posts is intended to find only posts whose status is certain, so that the correct action for the review is unambiguous. In this case, mod-deletion provides that certainty of status.

It was deleted by the moderator because there is no useful content other than a link. Answers which consist solely of links are not considered suitable for a variety of reasons, the primary one being that, should the resource at the other end of the link disappear, the answer becomes useless. They can be flagged for moderator attention, and are frequently deleted, although leaving a comment like the following for the author suggesting incorporating some of the linked-to material is not a bad idea

> While this may technically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) for you to summarize the linked material here. Otherwise, the answer is at risk of losing its usefulness due to link rot.

Further information about link-only answers can be had at [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: I have been educated.